# Finding the 3 largest numbers in an array/list of n numbers without the sorting

Tags: java, arrays, max

When I am doing my assignments I get really confused when I have to find the largest 3 numbers in a list of numbers(data structure not specified). I am totally struck with what I have to do. Any help?

Comment: Start with a `for-loop`, iterate through the list, compare each value against the three "largest" values/variables (which should be initialized to `0`) using something like `Math.max`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think the values should be initialized to the min value of the array, not `0`. In the case that all the numbers are negative, initializing at `0` wouldn't work.

Comment: @saadq This is true, I was thinking of positive numbers only.  You could use `Integer.MIN_VALUE` instead, then you don't need to know the range the array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep three variables to store three largest values, and iterating through the array:

You need to take care of three cases:

- When the current element greater than the largest element. Need to update second and third largest accordingly.
- When current element greater than second largest. Need to update third largest.
- When current element greater than third largest.

My [code](http://ideone.com/MudyOy) if you still stuck

```
for(int i : array)
    if(i > largest)
      //Do smt
    else if(i > second)
      //Do smt
    else if(i > third)
      //Do smt
```

Comment: Who does it help, in the long run, if you do someone's homework assignment for them?

Comment: @yshavit he still needs to understand this code, anyway. I don't think I can help if a person keeps being lazy and doesn't want to improve :)

Comment: @yshavit If I am lazy I would not even asked in this forum. I could have simply copied with my friends program. when I ask my doubts here I usually get many answers(logics).  Isn't this learning??? As a begineer I beleive learning more than logics for all programs I do. Thats why I asked

Comment: @RangaGanesh this is hard to justify, only you know it yourself, as long as you feel improve and learn smt, it is ok. And it is ok to look at solution, I think, I always look at the solution when I am stuck, then, after understanding it, I try to come up with my own solution, that the best way to learn in this situation, so I encourage you to come up with your own after reading mine :)

Comment: At first I thought of doing this problem with a max function which reurns a max value once the function is called. After finding that max value I should remove the value from the datastructure that I used to store the value. Then recrusively call the function for finding n max values. But the problem there is 3 times for loop is going to execute. But after I asked this question in this forum I understood y I want to exceute for loop for 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int firstNumber=5;
    int secondNumber=3;
    int thirdNumber=4;

    int largestNumber=(firstNumber>secondNumber)?firstNumber:(secondNumber>thirdNumber)?secondNumber:thirdNumber;
    System.out.println("largestNumber : "+largestNumber);
```

Comment: Isn't the OP asking for the `3 largest numbers in an array list of n numbers`? Why are you giving the largest number among 3 numbers?

Answer (score 0):

The really simple way:

```
    List<Number> numbers = new ArrayList<Number>();
    numbers.add(5);
    numbers.add(4);
    numbers.add(3);
    numbers.add(2);
    numbers.add(1);
    numbers.add(6);

    SortedSet<Number> sortedNumbers= new TreeSet<Number>();
    sortedNumbers.addAll(numbers);
    SortedSet<Number> subSet = sortedNumbers.subSet(sortedNumbers.size()-2, sortedNumbers.size()+1);
    for (Number subSet1 : subSet) {
        System.out.println(""+subSet1);
    }
```

Comment: Your use of a set excludes repeated digits (if any) that may also be among the largest.  OP did not specifically state that the list of numbers would be distinct.

Answer (score 0):

My leetcode solution in python3 in O(N) time complexity.

```
class Solution:
    def thirdMax(self, A: List[int]) -> int:
        sm=float('-inf')
        fm=float('-inf')
        tm=float('-inf')
        N=len(A)
        i=0
        while i<N:
            
            if A[i]>fm:
                tm=sm
                sm=fm
                fm=A[i]
            elif A[i]>sm and A[i]<fm:
                tm=sm
                sm=A[i]
            elif (A[i]>tm and A[i]<sm):
                tm=A[i]
            
            i+=1
            
             
        return tm if tm != float('-inf') else fm
```